# Display "Fn lock" OSD when "Fn + EscFnLock" key is pressed in thinkpad using Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I am using thinkpad X1 yoga with ubuntu 18.04. 
Currently OSD is not displayed when "Fn + EscfnLock" is pressed.
How can we display OSD when "Fn + EscfnLock" key is pressed ?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a link of the picture EscfnLock key?

Comment: Its "Escape" key ... Whenever we press Escape and Fn key, it toggles FnLock.

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't be possible. The [Fn-key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) is not a "key" that is recognised by the OS. It is used to access BIOS functions directly or modify other keys on the keyboard.

As the OS does not know about Fn, it is unlikely that it does know anything about FnLock.